# Xamarin Android (IIS EXPRESS VS 2015 ) Connecting WCF

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android, localhost

I am trying to connect from xamarin android emulator to my Visual Studio(2015) Wcf service but I'am getting (Connection refused) and 400 http badrequest

NOTE : I dont create web service to my localhost I am starting up from vs 2015.

```
  public Service1() {
        this.Url = "http://10.0.2.2:2486/Service1.svc";
        if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
            this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
        }
        else {
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
        }
    }


        // From my android application
      ` TrackingService.Service1 client=new Service1();
        var id = Android.OS.Build.Serial;
        client.IamOnBoard(id, "password");`
```

My WCF :

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void IamOnBoard(string id,string pass);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It shows your service running on port 2486 but you're trying to connect to port 80 in your code.

Comment: yes you are right.I edit my IISEXPRESS config file for port 80 but it doesnt start like config binder.At last I try it 10.0.2.2:2486  but the error is timeout

Comment: All you need can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3

Comment: Thank you :) I was not waiting for answer ..